# Ruby MiniTest: readable output from assert_equal

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is there a standard way to make failure output from `assert_equal` more readable?

```
test "compare" do
  assert_equal "some string", "some string that differs"
end
```

This produces:

```
MiniTest::Assertion: <"some string"> expected but was
<"some string that differs">.
```

Ideally the output would be aligned, and perhaps trimmed to show where they actually differ. The current output is fine for small strings, but it gets hard to discern where they differ when the strings are long.

Answer (score 0):

MiniTest has a diff() method that returns the diffing tool.  You can also set it. See this documentation.

[module MiniTest::Assertions](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-diff)